# How to fix endless loading on PC?

Tags: no-mans-sky

The game shows no errors and runs smoothly. The title comes up and the going forward among stars animation begins but nothing happens after that.

I'm using a PC. Does anyone know a fix for this?

Comment: Have you tried verifying the files?

Comment: How long did you wait? It's possible the game takes a bit longer to load than usual. It happened to me too.

Answer (score 4):

If this is the first time you have loaded the game or haven't started playing the game proper and the screen says Initialising.

You have to hold the E button down.

Comment: They need to make this more obvious... I thought it was still loading

Answer (score 3):

If stuck on "Initialise..." white screen:

There was a patch recently (around 8/22/219) - "beyond update" - that allows for the rebinding of keys again.  I had not played for a few years so my keys were still rebound but not "activated" because of the patches in between.

Solution: log into old save, rebind all keys that have a lower case letter instead of a caps letter in a square.  Then the activating screen actually showed a letter for me when starting a new game.

Answer (score 2):

This could simply be the game is still loading. The first load on PC can take a number of minutes and once it is complete and the screen says Initializing you must hold the use button (E by default).

Comment: Actually, I experienced this issue myself yesterday, on my 4th or 5th start of the game (not a "new" game, just starting the program). It eventually loaded though, but I did think it was bizarre; I wonder if it has to do with contacting the server at startup?